# Agential Realism and diffractive reading to analysis a specific topic

Tags: analytic-philosophy, materialism

together

I am currently facing a very big challenge, based on my studies. I am currently attending a seminar of New Materialism, which above all thematizes agential realism. An essential element here is the diffractive reading (based on Donna Haraway/ Karen Barad).
With the help of such a diffractive reading, ie reading across from a non-specialist perspective, a new approach to new knowledge is to be made possible. We shall exemplify this approach along an essay.

As a concrete topic, I would like to devote myself to cyborgs or human enhancement. So to what extent do we humans distinguish ourselves from these.

How can this question / task be solved with the help of diffractory reading?

Karan Barad speaks of apparatuses as methods of knowledge production. I think the literature research could be an apparatus in this essay. but how does it continue?
Can someone realtively simply name the steps I should take?
I know that I should study the theory of cyborgs from a non-specialist discipline, but how exactly is this done?

How would you suggest, what helpful tips and advice can you name?

I myself have never dealt with philosophy to this extent, which results in this challenge for me.

I am thankful for every answer!

Comment: Do you have a reference to Karen Barad's text? Perhaps also a quote regarding "apparatuses as methods of knowledge production". Welcome!

Comment: Sorry Frank, I can't find an appropriate quote for that...